# for spring hibernate project? xml based or annotation based?

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration, annotations

I am new In spring Technology.I am going to create a new project in spring hibernate with MySQL. but I am confused for configuration. I have to create a large project in spring 4 MVC with Hibernate MySQL.can you please tell me which one is best for the project? and, yes I also have to use Apache tiles.xml. which was mostly adopted in IT world? is there any way for use both as per requirement? like for Hibernate annotation based and for servlet and mapping XML based?

Comment: There is no best or bad design.. its upto which way like the most. But nowdays java based configuration approach is widely used

Comment: If one is "best" / "better" then there would be no reason for the other to exist. It is a preference.

Comment: I think its discussion based question.

Comment: I have no problem with better and best. I am an employee. I have to find my way for complete the project as soon as possible. so which one is easy for configuration?

Answer (score 0):

**The Pros of Hibernate Annotations**:

- Far more intuitive.
- Annotations are less verbose than their XML equivalents.
- Hibernate uses and supports the JPA 2 persistence annotations. If you elect not to use Hibernate-specific features in your code and annotations, you will have the freedom to deploy your entities to environments using other ORM tools that support JPA 2.

**The Cons of Hibernate Annotations**:

- Migrating from Hibernate 2 to Hibernate 3 is difficult.
- Maintaining the mapping information as external XML files allows that mapping information to be modified to reflect business changes or schema alterations without forcing you to rebuild the application as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

java Annotation based configuration is the best solution

XML Based

```
XML based configuration are still mailtained to provide backward compactablity to jdk 1.4

Advantage

1. When your running your appliation with 1.4 JDK or lesser
2. Provides good readablity 

Disadvantage

1. Application boot up will take longer time
2. Support has be readuced in lot of framework
```

Java Annotation based configuration is best

```
1. Most of the framework are now moved to annotation based
2. Light weight, boots faster than xml
3. Easy to maintain and code
```

Refer [spring mvc hello world example](http://java.candidjava.com/tutorial/Spring-mvc-hello-world-example.htm) with java based configuration

Refer updated [spring official guide](https://spring.io/guides)